# java program to copy files from/to mobile device

Tags: java, windows, connection, windows-mobile-6

Is there a java api that can be used to write a program on a desktop computer, a program to connect to a Windows Mobile 6 device and copy a file from/to the device?

Comment: see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481300/portable-device-path-on-windows using the windows remote developper powertoys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my question, why does the desktop device must waiting to connect the mobile device. It's not easier when you write a JavaME run on the mobile device. So when this found the desktop device, ask to send the file over bluetooth.

Comment: cause i need to send some data from the database on the mobile device to the desktop device for analyzing..