# Java: List Cameras that are Plugged In

Tags: java, camera, device

My program currently gets a list of drives plugged into the computer with `File.listRoots()`.  But, when I plug a camera or an MP3 player into the computer directly (instead of inserting the memory card), it's not listed, nor does it have a drive letter in Windows Explorer.  For example, here's the location of my camera:

```
Computer\Canon PowerShot SD750\Removable storage
```

How can I also list cameras/other devices that do not have a drive letter?  I assume this will require a JNI library of some sort, but I don't know for sure obviously.

Thanks!

P.S. Out of desperation, I *did* try to list the contents of `Computer\`; it didn't work of course.

---

**Update**: I found this question here: [Portable Device Path on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481300/portable-device-path-on-windows) ; that's exactly the problem I'm having, but there is no solution laid out there.

Answer (score 2):

Java 7 has some promising looking classes in this area, like this one:
http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html

Assuming that you need it to work on Java 6 as well, I would suggest running a shell script and parsing its output.
On Windows you could run mountvol, on Unix/MacOS X mount etc.  Of course parsing the output would be somewhat tedious and you would have to worry about every OS your app runs on, but hey, at least... not sure what.... it works?

[Here](http://www.cruto.com/resources/vbscript/vbscript-examples/storage/disks/drives/List-Volume-Properties.asp) is some sample code which seems helpful on Windows:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Volume")

For Each objItem In colItems
    WScript.Echo "Automount: " & objItem.Automount
    WScript.Echo "Block Size: " & objItem.BlockSize
    WScript.Echo "Capacity: " & objItem.Capacity
    WScript.Echo "Caption: " & objItem.Caption
    WScript.Echo "Compressed: " & objItem.Compressed
    WScript.Echo "Device ID: " & objItem.DeviceID
    WScript.Echo "Dirty Bit Set: " & objItem.DirtyBitSet
    WScript.Echo "Drive Letter: " & objItem.DriveLetter
    WScript.Echo "Drive Type: " & objItem.DriveType
    WScript.Echo "File System: " & objItem.FileSystem
    WScript.Echo "Free Space: " & objItem.FreeSpace
    WScript.Echo "Indexing Enabled: " & objItem.IndexingEnabled
    WScript.Echo "Label: " & objItem.Label
    WScript.Echo "Maximum File Name Length: " & objItem.MaximumFileNameLength
    WScript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
    WScript.Echo "Quotas Enabled: " & objItem.QuotasEnabled
    WScript.Echo "Quotas Incomplete: " & objItem.QuotasIncomplete
    WScript.Echo "Quotas Rebuilding: " & objItem.QuotasRebuilding
    WScript.Echo "Serial Number: " & objItem.SerialNumber
    WScript.Echo "Supports Disk Quotas: " & objItem.SupportsDiskQuotas
    WScript.Echo "Supports File-Based Compression: " & _
        objItem.SupportsFileBasedCompression
    WScript.Echo
Next
```

Here is the output I got for my ebook reader:

```
Automount: True
Block Size: 4096
Capacity: 999120896
Caption: G:\
Compressed: 
Device ID: \\?\Volume{8e3b4ce5-a124-11e0-9d2b-e30c5839642d}\
Dirty Bit Set: False
Drive Letter: G:
Drive Type: 2
File System: FAT32
Free Space: 663683072
Indexing Enabled: 
Label: PocketBook9
Maximum File Name Length: 255
Name: G:\
Quotas Enabled: 
Quotas Incomplete: 
Quotas Rebuilding: 
Serial Number: 1276177233
Supports Disk Quotas: False
Supports File-Based Compression: False
```

Comment: Too bad, I'm on the JRE6.  Could you give an example shell command with the information in my question?  I'm developing this program for Windows right now.

Comment: And I don't suppose there's a way to grab that library and use it in Java 6?

Comment: @Jonah I added some sample script you can get the info with.  I don't think you can use /Java7 features from java6.

Comment: @MK: I ran that VBScript in the console, but it did _not_ list the device.

Comment: @MK: How does your ebook reader's address come up in Windows Explorer?

Comment: That's all?  That's all the text in the address bar?

Comment: I think address bar just shows the drive letter, g:\  But when I look at the list of drives the label on drive g shows up as 'pocketbook9'.

Comment: @MK: Okay, yeah.  It has a drive letter, and it's not under the "Portable Devices" group.  The crazy thing is, it isn't even listed in a [folder selection dialog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/images/connector-cpp-mysql-include-select-directory-dialog.png).

Comment: I think if you are willing to use the approach of running an external script, you should post a new question asking "how do I write a script on Windows to enumerate my attached camera".  I don't even have a cable to plug my camera in, I always just take the sd card out :)

Comment: @MK: an excellent suggestion.  I suppose the script would have to mount the camera to some location so that Java can access it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to above problem using JMTP library on

```
http://code.google.com/p/jmtp/
```

Here is my code

```
    package jmtp;
```

```
import be.derycke.pieter.com.COMException;
import be.derycke.pieter.com.Guid;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import jmtp.PortableDevice;
import jmtp.*;

public class Jmtp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PortableDeviceManager manager = new PortableDeviceManager();
        PortableDevice device = manager.getDevices()[0];
        // Connect to my mp3-player
        device.open();

        System.out.println(device.getModel());

        System.out.println("---------------");

        // Iterate over deviceObjects
        for (PortableDeviceObject object : device.getRootObjects()) {
            // If the object is a storage object
            if (object instanceof PortableDeviceStorageObject) {
                PortableDeviceStorageObject storage = (PortableDeviceStorageObject) object;

                for (PortableDeviceObject o2 : storage.getChildObjects()) {
//                    
//                        BigInteger bigInteger1 = new BigInteger("123456789");
//                        File file = new File("c:/JavaAppletSigningGuide.pdf");
//                        try {
//                            storage.addAudioObject(file, "jj", "jj", bigInteger1);
//                        } catch (Exception e) {
//                            //System.out.println("Exception e = " + e);
//                        }
//                    

                    System.out.println(o2.getOriginalFileName());
                }
            }
        }

        manager.getDevices()[0].close();

    }
}
```

**Donot forget add jmtp.dll files (that comes up with jmtp download) as a native library for more info see my answer on**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798530/including-native-library-in-netbeans
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but is assigning them to a drive letter not an option? You can usually manually do this with USB devices on Windows using My Computer > right-click > Manage > Storage.

It's *possible* that CaptureDeviceManager in JMF (java media framework) could help you but I kind of doubt it.

Comment: This will be a commercially distributed piece of software, so unfortunately that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at Morena Framework http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.htmlv (seems to be open source, but a little expensive; though there is a free evaluation version), it is for TWAIN compatible scanners/cameras (Windows/MAC) or SANE compatible (Linux or other unix flavor), to get a list of connected devices, you can do this:

```
import SK.gnome.morena.*;
import SK.gnome.twain.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        TwainSource[] sources=TwainManager.listSources();
        if(sources == null) return;
        for(int i = 0; i < sources.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Twain source is: " + ts.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe that could help,if not I think maybe JMF is a possible solution.

Comment: I don't think that's quite what I'm looking for, that's for image devices, I just want to access a drive.