# Netbeans Java application does not run in windows XP, but does on windows 7; complains about class not found exception

Tags: java

I have a java application in netbeans, it will build and run from the command prompt in windows 7, then when I send the .jar to my windows XP virtual machine I get a exception when I try to run it.

`Exception in thread main, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jnativehook/mouse/NativeMouseInputListener`

I figure this exception means that my library JNativeHook is not being built with my .jar, but I know it is because it runs on my windows 7.

Any ideas?

Comment: Normally, when you build a project, dependent libraries need to be included as part of the deployment.  Depending on how you've built it, these "additional" libraries may be defined as part of the Jars class path from within the manifest file

Comment: You need to copy over any needed DLL's too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NativeMouseInputListener is a native class, so the path of the containing library on windows xp may be different from windows 7.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer, what do you mean a native class? And shouldn't the library file be compiled into the .jar?

Comment: @BumSkeeter Why?  Did you tell it to?

Comment: @BumSkeeter I am not sure of a way to convert a native library to a jar. I am not an expert but converting a native code written in c/c++ to java can be a tedious. That is why we use JNI to access native code.

Comment: How do I define the path in the .jar where it looks for the library?

Comment: @BumSkeeter I believe this is how you must be giving the path -Djava.library.path="C:/MyLibPath;%PATH%"

Comment: @BumSkeeter For netbeans follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798530/including-native-library-in-netbeans