# How to append library path to the java.library.path in the VM options in Netbeans

Tags: java

Dummy question but I spent half an hour looking for an answer

If I try to set it on runtime

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:\\Users\\elect\\Documents\\SixenseSDK_062612\\SixenseSDK_062612\\bin\\x64\\release_dll");
```

or

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:\\Users\\elect\\Documents\\SixenseSDK_062612\\SixenseSDK_062612\\bin\\x64\\release_dll\\");
```

it doesnt see the lib

if I put it in the VM option it works, but I want to append, neither %% or $ work

Ps: I am on win

Comment: My tip to you is to always distribute JNI DLL files in the same directory as the JAR file and you'll never have to worry about library paths again. Or if you know exactly where they're going to be installed in the target environment, use their full pathnames in the loadLibrary() call.

Comment: @EJP, thanks, I am gonna try it once at home

Answer (score 0):

Make use of

```
System.getProperty("java.library.path")
```

to append it using

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path")
```

Comment: Yeah but not sure if getProperty returns a string ending with a ';'

Comment: Yeah dont worry, I will check and if needed I will do it manually

Answer (score 0):

What kind of library do you want to add? 
If it's some java libraries (i.e. a jar) you want to change classpath instead.

cf. [How to setup classpath in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans)

You probably don't need to change library path unless you are using some custom native library (with a .dll in windows)

cf. [Including Native Library in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798530/including-native-library-in-netbeans)

Comment: I want to append DLLs and the answer you pointed me just overwrite it

Comment: The getProp/setProp method should work.
However It doesn't sound like a good idea to code some path in java classes.
If you really want to do that define at least your own property to update the lib path.

I also read that something like that can be done -Djava.library.path=${system_property:java.library.path}
However I don't manage to make it work.

Comment: Dont worry ^^. Anyway, I definitely agree with you, but as far as there is no other alternative, we are stuck on this..