# Import Android JNI shared library ".so" into Java Netbeans project?

Tags: java, android, netbeans, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I have a shared library, an `.so` library with a JNI interface. The `.so` library was built in Visual C++ 2017 with Android support. Now I want to import the .so library into a Java Netbeans project - is it possible?

Comment: If it was built for Android, it's probably compiled for ARM or something like that. ARM libraries won't run on PCs, unless they also have ARM CPUs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found this video how import Visual C++ JNI dll in Eclipse, Eclipse has the option to import Native Library Location, but Netbeans has something equals? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9oqGU6U_tI

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it with these posts:

http://electrofriends.com/articles/jni/jni-part1-java-native-interface/

http://electrofriends.com/articles/jni/part-2-jni-visual-studio-setup-dll-project/

[Including Native Library in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798530/including-native-library-in-netbeans)

1.- Create JNI Library .dll or .so in Visual Studio with DLL project or C++ Library For Android, no empty Project and with JDK reference:

a.- In Visual Studio Go to Project->Properties.

b.- On the left side, select C/C++, add jdk include and win32 path in Additional Include Directories.
If you have installed jdk in c program files then the path is

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\include; C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\include\win32

**if JDK is 64 bits plataform the DLL must be compile to x64.**

2.- In Netbeans:

a.-Right click on the Project Properties

b.- Click on RUN

c.- In VM Options TextBox add:

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\Your Directory where Dll is present".
```

c.- Finally call C++ method:

```
System.loadLibrary("JNILibreria");
```

The dll name complete  is for example JNILibreria.dll.