# Detect mobile device on windows with Java

Tags: java, windows-7-x64, usb-drive

I want to access my smartphone (samsung galaxy s4) via Java just like any other USB-drive but it does not show up in the list of drives:

```
File[] f = File.listRoots();
for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
    String drive = f[i].getPath();
    System.out.println("Drive: " + drive);
}
```

Windows seems to classify it as an mobile device.
Is there a simple way to detect it just like any other drive?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Windows normally sees the Galaxy S4 as an MTP device.  The S4’s USB options also let you configure it to be seen as a PTP device.  For MTP, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947921/best-method-for-copying-file-from-mtp-device-to-pc may help (though the jMTP library to which it links apparently hasn’t been touched in years).  For PTP, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498179/java-list-cameras-that-are-plugged-in may work.  Whatever you choose, I don’t think it will be easy or clean…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used [jMTPe](https://github.com/ultrah/jMTPe) to access my phone on windows and it works very well. Although it's only compatible with a 32bit JRE.