# Android: How to read files in Java app from MTP

Tags: java, android, read-write, mtp

I need to be able to read a phone's file system from a desktop application in Java.
I don't want to use adb.

In old android devices/versions there was Usb Mass Storage, but on all the newer devices this option doesn't exist.

So can some one help with a library and example code... What I need is:
1) Read files (the actual file and the file's properties including paths - I need to get only the .mp3s)
2) Write to specific locations

Thanks!

Comment: See this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481300/portable-device-path-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

I tried to read data from MTP using the jusbpmp library, but the following example code returned me an empty array of devices, although I had a connected android phone in working MTP mode:

```
dm = DeviceManager.getInstance();
dm.createInstance();
dm.scanDevices();
dm.dump();
```

Comment: Tried it myself just now, same thing :(